# Getting actionpack dependency issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While running bundle install or running any other command getting this issue

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    activerecord-session_store was resolved to 1.1.3, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 5.2)

```
rails (~> 5.1.7) was resolved to 5.1.7, which depends on
  actionpack (= 5.1.7)
```

I have multiple version installed in my machine.I have created the rails app using the specific version and getting this issue

Comment: Did you try adding "actionpack 5.1.7" explicitly in the gemfile ?

Comment: Yes I have tried. Still getting the same issue